# Replace main navigation links with submenu links on hover - instead of a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I recently saw a navigation effect I liked on a website, but can't find it to check the code and see how it was done. There was a standard menu bar that was 100% width and aprox 30px in height, with each link equally spaced within it. When you hovered on the gallery link the whole menu bar changed and the links were replaced with the submenu. No dropdown, the whole menu bar was changed to the submenu items. I can't quite sort out how this was done. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is the example html markup I am working with:

```
<nav>
    <ul class ="menu">
        <li class ="nav__item"><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
        <li class ="nav__item"><a href="galleries.html">galleries</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="one.html">one</a></li>
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="two.html">two</a></li>
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="three.html">three</a></li>
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="four.html">four</a></li>
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="five.html">five</a></li>
                <li class ="nav__subitem"><a href="six.html">six</a></li> 
            </ul> <!-- close sub -->
        </li>
        <li class ="nav__item"><a href="blog.html">stories</a></li>
        <li class ="nav__item"><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>  
        <li class ="nav__item"><a href="thankyou.html">thank you</a></li>     
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnt9wr4r/1/)**

Setting a fixed height to the navigation with relative positioning and targeting the parent of the nested ul on mouse over I was able to achieve this effect.

```
nav {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #999999;
}
.menu {
    list-style-type:none;
    position: relative;
}
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li.nav__item {
    float:left;
}
li.nav__item a {
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height:50px;
}
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:15px;
}
.nav__subitem {
    line-height: 50px;
    float: left;
    list-style: outside none none;
}
```

And the little bit of jQuery magic to tie it all together.

```
 $(".has-children").mouseover(function () {
        $(".menu").css("top", "-50px");
    });
    $(".main-navigation").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".menu").css("top", "0px");
    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much. And such a quick reply! This is almost exactly what I am looking for. It's maybe not as awesome on the UX side as I remember it being, but perhaps if I add a bit of a fade transition it will help. You rock! :)

Comment: one quick question. I added a transition to .menu (transition: all .3s ease-in-out;  ) which slows down what is happening, however the transition doesn't work on the initial mousover. It jumps initially and then any subsequent mousover is smooth. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Ernie;
Can you send a fiddle with your updated code, so I can play with it?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, here is a codepen I have it in: http://codepen.io/afrancis/pen/BooNZb

Comment: Sorry Ernie; Was out of town. Glad you got it resolved.